# IE8 looses some php session vars while keeping other intact on refresh or an ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, session

Have a big problem with php sessions on IE8 here. I've done some research on the web but no examples match (or I'm not capable of translating them into my scenario)

I have a site that makes an extensive use of session having multiple values and an array kept in session vars. Everything works fine on chrome and firefox but parts of the system break on IE8 as it seems to simply loose session information after refresh. All session vars on the site go through the same various actions including header(location) redirections, apache url rewrite etc.

Not all sessions vars tho. Here's example. When I log in and save an information to a session (eg.$_SESSION['user']), it works fine throughout the site and I'm not being logged out ($_SESSION['user'] is not being lost). A the same time tho I'm assigning different session vars and they can be lost on refresh even tho login var is still present

Here's some code for the part that doesn't work on IE8

1) I have a link on the page that allows to edit page you're viewing, let say link is /edititem/ID

2) clicking it links to a php file that retrieves item's data and saves a session var array. One of the fields in that array determines which html elements will be displayed on the edit form. After session vars are set up, there's a header() redirection

```
    session_start();
    $item = Item::getById($_GET["id"]);
    $_SESSION["item"]["type"] = $item->type;
    $_SESSION["item"]["title"] = $item->title;
    $_SESSION["item"]["action"] = "edit";
    header('location: /item_management');
```

3) when landing on /item_management page on IE8 following that redirection, everything is ok. When I refresh that page tho, that session information set above is gone

I read about possible problems with urls that include _ on IE8. I changed those urls at some stage to use - instead of _ but that didn't help, so I reverted.
I was also thinking it may be some problem with arrays in session but there's at least one more place in the code where non-array session is being lost when called in ajax call (I have $_SESSION["image"], do an ajax call, read that 'image' var in php called with ajax and it's empty).

Also, user session var is intact throughout the system, even tho other values go missing

All session related stuff works perfect on chrome/firefox

Any ideas? I will provide any piece of code required

Comment: Are you sure IE is accepting the session cookie? Is it just those variables missing, or is the whole session empty?

Comment: just those variables plus few others on the site (eg SESSION["image"] that I mentioned - it's getting lost on ajax call)... like I wrote, user session is intact... otherwise I would be logged out

Comment: did more tests and I'm not really sure what's going on. Session ID is definitely there throughout the whole site, including ajax calls. Very strange behavior that I discovered during tests is that if I have SESSION["ad"][] array and approx 10 values assigned to it, it will keep all those values after redirection, but will loose majority (but not all!!) of those values after refresh. I'm making sure that no other parts of the code manipulate with that session var on the way and there's no such code. I'm also unsetting session["ad"] each time before a new one is created

Comment: is there no one who can help?

Comment: Sorry, when questions are about things IE does wrong, my attention span decreases exponentially over time.

Comment: because you're fed up with IE or fed up with people that cannot code for IE

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same problem with my internal web application. Certain session variables, especially ones that were just updated into the database go missing upon refresh or even revert to older values of the variable. I have not found a solution so I've been having my users use a different browser than IE.

So I guess the only solution if you can is to let people know that IE has strange behavior and they should try to use a different browser if using your application.